# Java connection to MySql database, NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, connector, connector-j

I want to make Connection to MySql serwer with Java(without installing additional extension), and i'm getting "java.lang.NullPointerException" error.
Here are my codes
Main:

```
package sqlconnect;
public class SQLcONNECT {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DBConnect connect = new DBConnect();
    connect.getData();
    }    
}
```

and DBConnect:

```
package sqlconnect;
//https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
 import java.sql.*;

public class DBConnect {
private Connection  con; 
private Statement  st;
private  ResultSet  rs; 
String Query = "SELECT * FROM uczniowie;" ; 
public void DBConnect() 
{
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") ; 
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://serwer:port/BaseName","login","passwd"); 
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}

public void getData()  
{
    try
    {
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(Query);
        System.out.println("Rows from Table:");
        while(rs.next())
        {               
            String Uczen = rs.getString("Uczen"); 
            String CzyZda = rs.getString("CzyZda");
            String Ocena = rs.getString("Ocena");
            System.out.println("Uczen: " + Uczen +"  "+ "CzyZda: "+ CzyZda+"Ocena: "+Ocena);   
        }
    }
    catch(Exception  ex)
    {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
} }
```

What can be problem, and what can i made to solve that?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: How can i make that?

Comment: And i'm using linux Ubuntu MAte

Answer (score 3):

```
public void DBConnect()
```

This isn't a constructor: it's a regular method. This is never invoked because you don't invoke it explicitly.

Remove the `void`.

---

Additionally, don't catch the `Exception`. Just add `throws Exception` (or, hopefully, a more specific exception) to the method signature. Otherwise you can end up with an invalid, unusable instance of the class.

```
public DBConnect() throws Exception 
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") ; 
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://serwer:port/BaseName","login","passwd"); 
}
```

Comment: New error "Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'CEST' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: @Bombozaur666 There are several errors there; I suggest you read the message carefully and fix the problems. For example, the first one tells you exactly the class to use instead; the second one is telling you that you need to use, say `Europe/Berlin` instead, because `CEST` isn't a valid timezone etc.